# Adding dbcontext to service with string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, dbcontext

I want to be able to add service.adddbcontext<*T*>(); to the startup.cs file with the <*T*> as a **string**.

The end goal is to be able to loop through all context in the project and add the required service.

```
Type t = Type.GetType("myproject.Models.mydbContext");
services.AddDbContext<t>();
```

Currently I have this code in the startup.cs but I am getting the following error:

```
CS0118 C# 't' is a variable but is used like a type
```

Comment: You would need to invoke the method using reflection, but, what do you aim to achieve by this?

Comment: A generic argument must be a static known type at compile time. It looks like you want to register types with the DI system dynamically at run time. A better way to achieve this could be to specify a type in a config file that does this for you. You call the configured type at runtime which has a predifined signature and pass in arguments like the `services` instance and it registers what it needs to.

Comment: @Ric I want to be able to register multiple dbcontext to the service without having to add manually each time

Comment: @Igor as the connection string from the full service.adddbcontext<mydbcontext>("name=myconnection"); can be retrieved from the appsettings.json. Is it possible to reference the db to be some like service.adddbcontext<"name=mydbcontext1">("name=myconnection"); ?

Comment: Doing this via reflection is just going to be confusing, it's much simpler to just add a line for every context.

Comment: @DavidG the goal is to be able to not add a line for every context manually I plan to have more than 10 dbcontext.

Comment: Then add 10 lines, what is the problem with that? Reflection code will probably 20 lines and harder to read.

Comment: @DavidG I could also have 50,60,70 dbcontext. I would rather have to do it once with 20 lines instead of adding 50 lines of adddbcontext

Comment: Do you really have 50 contexts? If so, then you have other huge problems.

Comment: @DavidG can you explain what problem would it have? currently I do not have that many contexts, but as the project goes along I plan to avoid having to add the service manually.

Comment: If I need to explain why 50 different DbContexts is a bad idea, then I think you might have more fundamental issues with your level of knowledge. Do you really have 50 different database structures?

Comment: @DavidG as I have said I do not have that many context now and of course not that many database structures as of yet. I am new to using netcore,ef and mvc, I do not know if your point here is to mock me for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I am not mocking at all, just stating a fact. I'm just pointing out that I've been writing software for a very long time and I've never seen a project with more than 7 or 8 different database structures.

Comment: @DavidG I see. I would like to try adding multiple dbcontext without manually typing into startup.cs when the need arises which was why I asked this question.

Comment: `I would like to try adding multiple dbcontext without manually typing into startup.cs when the need arises...` @Lenny I believe DavidG's point was there should never be a need which I concur with. As there will not be a need I would not focus my effort on trying to "fix" a problem that does not exist (with a difficult to maintain solution at that). Many times the easy solution is also the correct one.

Comment: I concur with others, 50 contexts? there is a fundamental design issue here.